# getting multiple discreet ticks rather than regular intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiywW.png)How to get regular intervals in scatter plot in all x and y axes.[check the x and y axes of the graph how to end these congestion and put ticks in regular intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOOKV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

plot.xticks(ticks=np.arange(min_x,max_x,step_x), labels=np.arange(min_x,max_x,step_x))

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide a hell lot of information, here a general answer[*](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-change-the-frequency-of-ticks-in-a-matplotlib-figure-in-python):

Use numpy to create an array with your ticks:

```
x_ticks = np.arange(min_value, max_value + interval, interval)
```

Thereby you use the minimal value of your data, the maximal value and the interval you want. You can also determine the needed interval automatically. Let us say that you want to only display 10 before the maximum:

```
interval = (max_value - min_value) / 10
```

For min=0 and max=20 this would mean you would have a tick at 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20

Then simply set the xticks:

```
plt.xticks(x_ticks)
```

Here's some exmaple code to show the functionality:

```
import numpy as np
min_ = 0
max_ = 20
count = 10
distance = max_ - min_
interval = distance / count
array = np.arange(min_, max_ + interval, interval)
print(array)
print(len(array))
```